How to make bootstrap column align top?
When one column has more content than the others, I want to make sure the other columns in the second row fill the empty space without causing gaps. The other row will also see the same thing. I'm utilizing bootstrap 5.
The layout i make -

I do tried to ensure that the columns in the second row line correctly and fill the remaining space without leaving gaps where one column contains more material than others using align-items-start. Still not working.
I am expecting the layout like this -
<div class="row mt-3 align-items-start">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="jdgm-rev position-relative card shadow-sm p-3 pb-1 jdgm-divider-top jdgm--done-setup jdgm--leex-done-setup flex-grow-1"
                            style="width: 100%;" data-verified-buyer="true"
                            data-review-id="36effdc2-6b57-46c4-abd7-6f6a798a7d30"
                            data-product-title="Lumivyx HaloClean UV"
                            data-product-url="/product/lumivyx-haloclean-uv-sanitizer/" data-thumb-up-count="0"
                            data-thumb-down-count="0" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
                            <div class="jdgm-rev__header">
                                <div class="jdgm-row-product"></div>
                                <div class="jdgm-row-rating"><span class="jdgm-rev__rating" data-score="5" tabindex="0"
                                        aria-label="5 star review" role="img"> <span
                                            class="jdgm-star jdgm--on"></span><span
                                            class="jdgm-star jdgm--on"></span><span
                                            class="jdgm-star jdgm--on"></span><span
                                            class="jdgm-star jdgm--on"></span><span class="jdgm-star jdgm--on"></span>
                                    </span><span class="jdgm-rev__timestamp"
                                        data-content="2024-10-10 18:29:40 UTC">10/10/2024</span></div>
                                <div class="jdgm-row-profile mt-2 mb-2">
                                    <div class="jdgm-rev__icon"></div><span class="jdgm-rev__author-wrapper">
                                        <svg style="margin-right: 6px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="24" height="24" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 464 464" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" class=""><g><path d="M305.872 451.92a209.097 209.097 0 0 1-7.296 2.336c2.456-.736 4.88-1.528 7.296-2.336zM317.992 447.472c-2.608 1.04-5.216 2.064-7.872 3.008a231.662 231.662 0 0 0 7.872-3.008z" style="" fill="#f9ede0" data-original="#f9ede0"></path><circle cx="232" cy="232" r="232" style="" fill="#efece8" data-original="#efece8" class=""></circle><path d="M293.896 455.584zM215.192 463.328c-2.832-.2-5.656-.416-8.448-.72 2.8.304 5.624.52 8.448.72zM177.256 457.44c-2.4-.584-4.784-1.208-7.16-1.864 2.376.664 4.76 1.288 7.16 1.864zM201.944 462a236.382 236.382 0 0 1-7.576-1.08c2.504.408 5.04.744 7.576 1.08zM232 464zM189.416 460.032zM142.608 446.128zM153.872 450.48zM244.72 463.64zM257.256 462.608c-2.8.304-5.624.52-8.448.72 2.824-.2 5.648-.416 8.448-.72zM281.848 458.576zM269.64 460.912c-2.512.408-5.04.752-7.576 1.08 2.528-.328 5.064-.664 7.576-1.08zM332.032 441.368a235.234 235.234 0 0 1-10.64 4.76 226.642 226.642 0 0 0 10.64-4.76zM165.424 454.256zM321.392 446.128c-1.12.472-2.264.888-3.392 1.336 1.12-.448 2.264-.864 3.392-1.336zM332.352 441.224c-.104.048-.216.096-.32.144.104-.048.216-.088.32-.144zM182.152 458.576zM194.36 460.912a256.257 256.257 0 0 1-4.952-.88c1.656.304 3.296.616 4.952.88zM219.28 463.64c-1.368-.072-2.728-.216-4.088-.312 1.368.096 2.72.24 4.088.312zM206.744 462.608c-1.608-.176-3.2-.4-4.8-.608 1.6.208 3.192.432 4.8.608zM131.928 441.352c-.088-.04-.184-.08-.272-.12.088.04.184.08.272.12zM248.808 463.328c-1.368.096-2.72.24-4.088.312 1.368-.072 2.72-.216 4.088-.312zM298.576 454.256zM310.128 450.48c-1.408.504-2.832.96-4.248 1.44 1.416-.48 2.84-.936 4.248-1.44zM146.008 447.472c-1.128-.448-2.272-.872-3.392-1.336 1.12.464 2.264.88 3.392 1.336zM158.128 451.92c-1.416-.48-2.848-.936-4.248-1.44 1.4.504 2.824.96 4.248 1.44zM262.056 462c-1.6.208-3.192.44-4.8.608 1.608-.176 3.2-.4 4.8-.608zM286.744 457.44c-1.624.392-3.256.768-4.896 1.128 1.64-.352 3.272-.728 4.896-1.128zM274.584 460.032c-1.648.304-3.288.616-4.952.88 1.664-.264 3.304-.576 4.952-.88zM170.104 455.584c-1.56-.432-3.128-.864-4.68-1.328 1.552.464 3.112.896 4.68 1.328z" style="" fill="#f9ede0" data-original="#f9ede0"></path><path d="M285.104 247.952C310.952 230.744 328 201.376 328 168c0-53.016-42.984-96-96-96s-96 42.984-96 96c0 33.376 17.048 62.744 42.896 79.952 0 0 .008.008.016.008-.008 0-.008-.008-.008-.008-61.872 18.648-110.048 68.864-125.56 132.04l.008.008a237.163 237.163 0 0 0 7.832 8.944c.648.712 1.328 1.392 1.992 2.088a239.937 239.937 0 0 0 6.296 6.464c.888.872 1.792 1.712 2.696 2.568a233.567 233.567 0 0 0 6.04 5.568c1.016.896 2.048 1.784 3.072 2.664 2.008 1.72 4.04 3.408 6.112 5.056 1.088.872 2.184 1.728 3.28 2.584a214.91 214.91 0 0 0 6.376 4.72c1.112.792 2.208 1.6 3.336 2.376 2.272 1.568 4.584 3.072 6.912 4.56 1.048.664 2.072 1.352 3.128 2.008a237.722 237.722 0 0 0 8.184 4.792c.728.408 1.44.848 2.176 1.248a231.937 231.937 0 0 0 10.872 5.592c.088.04.184.08.272.12 3.512 1.68 7.08 3.272 10.688 4.776 1.12.472 2.264.888 3.392 1.336 2.608 1.04 5.216 2.064 7.872 3.008 1.408.504 2.832.96 4.248 1.44 2.416.816 4.848 1.608 7.296 2.336 1.552.464 3.112.896 4.68 1.328 2.368.656 4.752 1.28 7.16 1.864a219.555 219.555 0 0 0 12.152 2.584c1.648.304 3.288.616 4.952.88 2.512.408 5.04.752 7.576 1.08 1.6.208 3.192.44 4.8.608 2.8.304 5.624.52 8.448.72 1.368.096 2.72.24 4.088.312 4.216.24 8.448.376 12.72.376s8.504-.136 12.72-.36c1.368-.072 2.728-.216 4.088-.312 2.832-.2 5.656-.416 8.448-.72 1.608-.176 3.2-.4 4.8-.608 2.536-.328 5.064-.672 7.576-1.08 1.656-.272 3.304-.576 4.952-.88a215.477 215.477 0 0 0 12.152-2.584c2.4-.584 4.784-1.208 7.16-1.864 1.56-.432 3.128-.864 4.68-1.328 2.456-.736 4.88-1.528 7.296-2.336 1.416-.48 2.848-.936 4.248-1.44a245.374 245.374 0 0 0 7.872-3.008c1.128-.448 2.272-.872 3.392-1.336a226.642 226.642 0 0 0 10.64-4.76c.104-.048.216-.096.32-.144 3.68-1.768 7.304-3.64 10.872-5.592.736-.4 1.448-.84 2.176-1.248a237.722 237.722 0 0 0 8.184-4.792c1.056-.648 2.088-1.336 3.128-2.008 2.328-1.488 4.64-3 6.912-4.56 1.12-.776 2.224-1.576 3.336-2.376a247.51 247.51 0 0 0 6.376-4.72 202.128 202.128 0 0 0 3.28-2.584 230.055 230.055 0 0 0 6.112-5.056c1.032-.88 2.064-1.768 3.072-2.664a233.567 233.567 0 0 0 6.04-5.568c.896-.856 1.808-1.704 2.696-2.568a228.37 228.37 0 0 0 6.296-6.464c.656-.704 1.336-1.384 1.992-2.088 2.68-2.92 5.304-5.896 7.832-8.944l.008-.008c-15.504-63.184-63.68-113.4-125.552-132.048z" style="" fill="#c6c3bd" data-original="#c6c3bd" class=""></path></g></svg>
                                         <span
                                            class="jdgm-rev__author">Mary Ann McCarthy</span> <span
                                            class="jdgm-rev__buyer-badge-wrapper"> <span
                                                class="jdgm-rev__buyer-badge"></span> </span></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="jdgm-row-extra"><span class="jdgm-rev__location"> </span></div>
                                <div class="jdgm-rev__br"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="jdgm-rev__content"> <b class="jdgm-rev__title">Getting rid of bed bugs and other
                                    insects.</b>
                                <div class="jdgm-rev__body">
                                    <p>Some how I contracted bed bugs in my home. Thank goodness it was a mild case and
                                        I caught it early
                                        <br>With this light and other treatments they are gone. Only took 4 weeks.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="jdgm-rev__custom-form"> </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="jdgm-rev__actions">
                                <div class="jdgm-rev__social"></div>
                                <div class="jdgm-rev__votes"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="jdgm-rev position-relative card shadow-sm p-3 pb-1 jdgm-divider-top jdgm--done-setup jdgm--leex-done-setup flex-grow-1"
                            style="width: 100%;" data-verified-buyer="true"
                            data-review-id="36effdc2-6b57-46c4-abd7-6f6a798a7d30"
                            data-product-title="Lumivyx HaloClean UV"
                            data-product-url="/product/lumivyx-haloclean-uv-sanitizer/" data-thumb-up-count="0"
                            data-thumb-down-count="0" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
                            <div class="jdgm-rev__header">
                                <div class="jdgm-row-product"></div>
                                <div class="jdgm-row-rating"><span class="jdgm-rev__rating" data-score="5" tabindex="0"
                                        aria-label="5 star review" role="img"> <span
                                            class="jdgm-star jdgm--on"></span><span
                                            class="jdgm-star jdgm--on"></span><span
                                            class="jdgm-star jdgm--on"></span><span
                                            class="jdgm-star jdgm--on"></span><span class="jdgm-star jdgm--on"></span>
                                    </span><span class="jdgm-rev__timestamp"
                                        data-content="2024-10-10 18:29:40 UTC">10/10/2024</span></div>
                                <div class="jdgm-row-profile mt-2 mb-2">
                                    <div class="jdgm-rev__icon"></div><span class="jdgm-rev__author-wrapper">
                                        <svg style="margin-right: 6px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="24" height="24" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 464 464" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" class=""><g><path d="M305.872 451.92a209.097 209.097 0 0 1-7.296 2.336c2.456-.736 4.88-1.528 7.296-2.336zM317.992 447.472c-2.608 1.04-5.216 2.064-7.872 3.008a231.662 231.662 0 0 0 7.872-3.008z" style="" fill="#f9ede0" data-original="#f9ede0"></path><circle cx="232" cy="232" r="232" style="" fill="#efece8" data-original="#efece8" class=""></circle><path d="M293.896 455.584zM215.192 463.328c-2.832-.2-5.656-.416-8.448-.72 2.8.304 5.624.52 8.448.72zM177.256 457.44c-2.4-.584-4.784-1.208-7.16-1.864 2.376.664 4.76 1.288 7.16 1.864zM201.944 462a236.382 236.382 0 0 1-7.576-1.08c2.504.408 5.04.744 7.576 1.08zM232 464zM189.416 460.032zM142.608 446.128zM153.872 450.48zM244.72 463.64zM257.256 462.608c-2.8.304-5.624.52-8.448.72 2.824-.2 5.648-.416 8.448-.72zM281.848 458.576zM269.64 460.912c-2.512.408-5.04.752-7.576 1.08 2.528-.328 5.064-.664 7.576-1.08zM332.032 441.368a235.234 235.234 0 0 1-10.64 4.76 226.642 226.642 0 0 0 10.64-4.76zM165.424 454.256zM321.392 446.128c-1.12.472-2.264.888-3.392 1.336 1.12-.448 2.264-.864 3.392-1.336zM332.352 441.224c-.104.048-.216.096-.32.144.104-.048.216-.088.32-.144zM182.152 458.576zM194.36 460.912a256.257 256.257 0 0 1-4.952-.88c1.656.304 3.296.616 4.952.88zM219.28 463.64c-1.368-.072-2.728-.216-4.088-.312 1.368.096 2.72.24 4.088.312zM206.744 462.608c-1.608-.176-3.2-.4-4.8-.608 1.6.208 3.192.432 4.8.608zM131.928 441.352c-.088-.04-.184-.08-.272-.12.088.04.184.08.272.12zM248.808 463.328c-1.368.096-2.72.24-4.088.312 1.368-.072 2.72-.216 4.088-.312zM298.576 454.256zM310.128 450.48c-1.408.504-2.832.96-4.248 1.44 1.416-.48 2.84-.936 4.248-1.44zM146.008 447.472c-1.128-.448-2.272-.872-3.392-1.336 1.12.464 2.264.88 3.392 1.336zM158.128 451.92c-1.416-.48-2.848-.936-4.248-1.44 1.4.504 2.824.96 4.248 1.44zM262.056 462c-1.6.208-3.192.44-4.8.608 1.608-.176 3.2-.4 4.8-.608zM286.744 457.44c-1.624.392-3.256.768-4.896 1.128 1.64-.352 3.272-.728 4.896-1.128zM274.584 460.032c-1.648.304-3.288.616-4.952.88 1.664-.264 3.304-.576 4.952-.88zM170.104 455.584c-1.56-.432-3.128-.864-4.68-1.328 1.552.464 3.112.896 4.68 1.328z" style="" fill="#f9ede0" data-original="#f9ede0"></path><path d="M285.104 247.952C310.952 230.744 328 201.376 328 168c0-53.016-42.984-96-96-96s-96 42.984-96 96c0 33.376 17.048 62.744 42.896 79.952 0 0 .008.008.016.008-.008 0-.008-.008-.008-.008-61.872 18.648-110.048 68.864-125.56 132.04l.008.008a237.163 237.163 0 0 0 7.832 8.944c.648.712 1.328 1.392 1.992 2.088a239.937 239.937 0 0 0 6.296 6.464c.888.872 1.792 1.712 2.696 2.568a233.567 233.567 0 0 0 6.04 5.568c1.016.896 2.048 1.784 3.072 2.664 2.008 1.72 4.04 3.408 6.112 5.056 1.088.872 2.184 1.728 3.28 2.584a214.91 214.91 0 0 0 6.376 4.72c1.112.792 2.208 1.6 3.336 2.376 2.272 1.568 4.584 3.072 6.912 4.56 1.048.664 2.072 1.352 3.128 2.008a237.722 237.722 0 0 0 8.184 4.792c.728.408 1.44.848 2.176 1.248a231.937 231.937 0 0 0 10.872 5.592c.088.04.184.08.272.12 3.512 1.68 7.08 3.272 10.688 4.776 1.12.472 2.264.888 3.392 1.336 2.608 1.04 5.216 2.064 7.872 3.008 1.408.504 2.832.96 4.248 1.44 2.416.816 4.848 1.608 7.296 2.336 1.552.464 3.112.896 4.68 1.328 2.368.656 4.752 1.28 7.16 1.864a219.555 219.555 0 0 0 12.152 2.584c1.648.304 3.288.616 4.952.88 2.512.408 5.04.752 7.576 1.08 1.6.208 3.192.44 4.8.608 2.8.304 5.624.52 8.448.72 1.368.096 2.72.24 4.088.312 4.216.24 8.448.376 12.72.376s8.504-.136 12.72-.36c1.368-.072 2.728-.216 4.088-.312 2.832-.2 5.656-.416 8.448-.72 1.608-.176 3.2-.4 4.8-.608 2.536-.328 5.064-.672 7.576-1.08 1.656-.272 3.304-.576 4.952-.88a215.477 215.477 0 0 0 12.152-2.584c2.4-.584 4.784-1.208 7.16-1.864 1.56-.432 3.128-.864 4.68-1.328 2.456-.736 4.88-1.528 7.296-2.336 1.416-.48 2.848-.936 4.248-1.44a245.374 245.374 0 0 0 7.872-3.008c1.128-.448 2.272-.872 3.392-1.336a226.642 226.642 0 0 0 10.64-4.76c.104-.048.216-.096.32-.144 3.68-1.768 7.304-3.64 10.872-5.592.736-.4 1.448-.84 2.176-1.248a237.722 237.722 0 0 0 8.184-4.792c1.056-.648 2.088-1.336 3.128-2.008 2.328-1.488 4.64-3 6.912-4.56 1.12-.776 2.224-1.576 3.336-2.376a247.51 247.51 0 0 0 6.376-4.72 202.128 202.128 0 0 0 3.28-2.584 230.055 230.055 0 0 0 6.112-5.056c1.032-.88 2.064-1.768 3.072-2.664a233.567 233.567 0 0 0 6.04-5.568c.896-.856 1.808-1.704 2.696-2.568a228.37 228.37 0 0 0 6.296-6.464c.656-.704 1.336-1.384 1.992-2.088 2.68-2.92 5.304-5.896 7.832-8.944l.008-.008c-15.504-63.184-63.68-113.4-125.552-132.048z" style="" fill="#c6c3bd" data-original="#c6c3bd" class=""></path></g></svg>
                                         <span
                                            class="jdgm-rev__author">U.A.</span> <span
                                            class="jdgm-rev__buyer-badge-wrapper"> <span
                                                class="jdgm-rev__buyer-badge"></span> </span></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="jdgm-row-extra"><span class="jdgm-rev__location"> </span></div>
                                <div class="jdgm-rev__br"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="jdgm-rev__content"> <b class="jdgm-rev__title">Great</b>
                                
                                <div class="jdgm-rev__custom-form"> </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="jdgm-rev__actions">
                                <div class="jdgm-rev__social"></div>
                                <div class="jdgm-rev__votes"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="jdgm-rev position-relative card shadow-sm p-3 pb-1 jdgm-divider-top jdgm--done-setup jdgm--leex-done-setup flex-grow-1"
                            style="width: 100%;" data-verified-buyer="true"
                            data-review-id="36effdc2-6b57-46c4-abd7-6f6a798a7d30"
                            data-product-title="Lumivyx HaloClean UV"
                            data-product-url="/product/lumivyx-haloclean-uv-sanitizer/" data-thumb-up-count="0"
                            data-thumb-down-count="0" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
                            <div class="jdgm-rev__header">
                                <div class="jdgm-row-product"></div>
                                <div class="jdgm-row-rating"><span class="jdgm-rev__rating" data-score="5" tabindex="0"
                                        aria-label="5 star review" role="img"> <span
                                            class="jdgm-star jdgm--on"></span><span
                                            class="jdgm-star jdgm--on"></span><span
                                            class="jdgm-star jdgm--on"></span><span
                                            class="jdgm-star jdgm--on"></span><span class="jdgm-star jdgm--on"></span>
                                    </span><span class="jdgm-rev__timestamp"
                                        data-content="2024-10-10 18:29:40 UTC">10/10/2024</span></div>
                                <div class="jdgm-row-profile mt-2 mb-2">
                                    <div class="jdgm-rev__icon"></div><span class="jdgm-rev__author-wrapper">
                                        <svg style="margin-right: 6px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="24" height="24" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 464 464" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" class=""><g><path d="M305.872 451.92a209.097 209.097 0 0 1-7.296 2.336c2.456-.736 4.88-1.528 7.296-2.336zM317.992 447.472c-2.608 1.04-5.216 2.064-7.872 3.008a231.662 231.662 0 0 0 7.872-3.008z" style="" fill="#f9ede0" data-original="#f9ede0"></path><circle cx="232" cy="232" r="232" style="" fill="#efece8" data-original="#efece8" class=""></circle><path d="M293.896 455.584zM215.192 463.328c-2.832-.2-5.656-.416-8.448-.72 2.8.304 5.624.52 8.448.72zM177.256 457.44c-2.4-.584-4.784-1.208-7.16-1.864 2.376.664 4.76 1.288 7.16 1.864zM201.944 462a236.382 236.382 0 0 1-7.576-1.08c2.504.408 5.04.744 7.576 1.08zM232 464zM189.416 460.032zM142.608 446.128zM153.872 450.48zM244.72 463.64zM257.256 462.608c-2.8.304-5.624.52-8.448.72 2.824-.2 5.648-.416 8.448-.72zM281.848 458.576zM269.64 460.912c-2.512.408-5.04.752-7.576 1.08 2.528-.328 5.064-.664 7.576-1.08zM332.032 441.368a235.234 235.234 0 0 1-10.64 4.76 226.642 226.642 0 0 0 10.64-4.76zM165.424 454.256zM321.392 446.128c-1.12.472-2.264.888-3.392 1.336 1.12-.448 2.264-.864 3.392-1.336zM332.352 441.224c-.104.048-.216.096-.32.144.104-.048.216-.088.32-.144zM182.152 458.576zM194.36 460.912a256.257 256.257 0 0 1-4.952-.88c1.656.304 3.296.616 4.952.88zM219.28 463.64c-1.368-.072-2.728-.216-4.088-.312 1.368.096 2.72.24 4.088.312zM206.744 462.608c-1.608-.176-3.2-.4-4.8-.608 1.6.208 3.192.432 4.8.608zM131.928 441.352c-.088-.04-.184-.08-.272-.12.088.04.184.08.272.12zM248.808 463.328c-1.368.096-2.72.24-4.088.312 1.368-.072 2.72-.216 4.088-.312zM298.576 454.256zM310.128 450.48c-1.408.504-2.832.96-4.248 1.44 1.416-.48 2.84-.936 4.248-1.44zM146.008 447.472c-1.128-.448-2.272-.872-3.392-1.336 1.12.464 2.264.88 3.392 1.336zM158.128 451.92c-1.416-.48-2.848-.936-4.248-1.44 1.4.504 2.824.96 4.248 1.44zM262.056 462c-1.6.208-3.192.44-4.8.608 1.608-.176 3.2-.4 4.8-.608zM286.744 457.44c-1.624.392-3.256.768-4.896 1.128 1.64-.352 3.272-.728 4.896-1.128zM274.584 460.032c-1.648.304-3.288.616-4.952.88 1.664-.264 3.304-.576 4.952-.88zM170.104 455.584c-1.56-.432-3.128-.864-4.68-1.328 1.552.464 3.112.896 4.68 1.328z" style="" fill="#f9ede0" data-original="#f9ede0"></path><path d="M285.104 247.952C310.952 230.744 328 201.376 328 168c0-53.016-42.984-96-96-96s-96 42.984-96 96c0 33.376 17.048 62.744 42.896 79.952 0 0 .008.008.016.008-.008 0-.008-.008-.008-.008-61.872 18.648-110.048 68.864-125.56 132.04l.008.008a237.163 237.163 0 0 0 7.832 8.944c.648.712 1.328 1.392 1.992 2.088a239.937 239.937 0 0 0 6.296 6.464c.888.872 1.792 1.712 2.696 2.568a233.567 233.567 0 0 0 6.04 5.568c1.016.896 2.048 1.784 3.072 2.664 2.008 1.72 4.04 3.408 6.112 5.056 1.088.872 2.184 1.728 3.28 2.584a214.91 214.91 0 0 0 6.376 4.72c1.112.792 2.208 1.6 3.336 2.376 2.272 1.568 4.584 3.072 6.912 4.56 1.048.664 2.072 1.352 3.128 2.008a237.722 237.722 0 0 0 8.184 4.792c.728.408 1.44.848 2.176 1.248a231.937 231.937 0 0 0 10.872 5.592c.088.04.184.08.272.12 3.512 1.68 7.08 3.272 10.688 4.776 1.12.472 2.264.888 3.392 1.336 2.608 1.04 5.216 2.064 7.872 3.008 1.408.504 2.832.96 4.248 1.44 2.416.816 4.848 1.608 7.296 2.336 1.552.464 3.112.896 4.68 1.328 2.368.656 4.752 1.28 7.16 1.864a219.555 219.555 0 0 0 12.152 2.584c1.648.304 3.288.616 4.952.88 2.512.408 5.04.752 7.576 1.08 1.6.208 3.192.44 4.8.608 2.8.304 5.624.52 8.448.72 1.368.096 2.72.24 4.088.312 4.216.24 8.448.376 12.72.376s8.504-.136 12.72-.36c1.368-.072 2.728-.216 4.088-.312 2.832-.2 5.656-.416 8.448-.72 1.608-.176 3.2-.4 4.8-.608 2.536-.328 5.064-.672 7.576-1.08 1.656-.272 3.304-.576 4.952-.88a215.477 215.477 0 0 0 12.152-2.584c2.4-.584 4.784-1.208 7.16-1.864 1.56-.432 3.128-.864 4.68-1.328 2.456-.736 4.88-1.528 7.296-2.336 1.416-.48 2.848-.936 4.248-1.44a245.374 245.374 0 0 0 7.872-3.008c1.128-.448 2.272-.872 3.392-1.336a226.642 226.642 0 0 0 10.64-4.76c.104-.048.216-.096.32-.144 3.68-1.768 7.304-3.64 10.872-5.592.736-.4 1.448-.84 2.176-1.248a237.722 237.722 0 0 0 8.184-4.792c1.056-.648 2.088-1.336 3.128-2.008 2.328-1.488 4.64-3 6.912-4.56 1.12-.776 2.224-1.576 3.336-2.376a247.51 247.51 0 0 0 6.376-4.72 202.128 202.128 0 0 0 3.28-2.584 230.055 230.055 0 0 0 6.112-5.056c1.032-.88 2.064-1.768 3.072-2.664a233.567 233.567 0 0 0 6.04-5.568c.896-.856 1.808-1.704 2.696-2.568a228.37 228.37 0 0 0 6.296-6.464c.656-.704 1.336-1.384 1.992-2.088 2.68-2.92 5.304-5.896 7.832-8.944l.008-.008c-15.504-63.184-63.68-113.4-125.552-132.048z" style="" fill="#c6c3bd" data-original="#c6c3bd" class=""></path></g></svg>
                                         <span
                                            class="jdgm-rev__author">Lawrence Rohm</span> <span
                                            class="jdgm-rev__buyer-badge-wrapper"> <span
                                                class="jdgm-rev__buyer-badge"></span> </span></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="jdgm-row-extra"><span class="jdgm-rev__location"> </span></div>
                                <div class="jdgm-rev__br"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="jdgm-rev__content"> <b class="jdgm-rev__title">Great product</b>
                               
                                <div class="jdgm-rev__custom-form"> </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="jdgm-rev__actions">
                                <div class="jdgm-rev__social"></div>
                                <div class="jdgm-rev__votes"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

